# Calculating Operation Count of this code

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the operation count of the code given below.

```
void add(matrix a, matrix b, matrix c, int m, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        count++; //for 'for' i   -------(a)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            count++; //for 'for' j  -------(b)
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            count++;    //for assignment ------(c)
        }
        count++;    //for last time of 'for' j  ------(d)
    }

    count++;    //for lastime of 'for' i ---------(e)
}
```

The variable count has been used by the author in which this code is to calculate operation count. I do know that the declarative statements (int i = 0; int j = 0) have operation count of 0.

Every time each the for loop will run it, the following expressions should do 2 operation counts for i < m; i++ when only 1 operation i < m is performed.

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)

for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
```

But the author has only calculated it once (a) and (b). Does that means i < m and j < n is not calculated in operation count?

In this line the operation count should be 2: 1 addition operation and 1 assignment operation.

```
 c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
```

Again he has only calculated it once (c).

Because of the questions I don't know why he incremented count at (d) and (e).

```
    //Simplified program with counting only
    line void add (matrix a, matrix b, matrix c, int m, int n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                count += 2;

            count += 2;
        }

        count++;

    }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Memory writes/reads (assignments) are often not counted when flops are concerned. You could also ask why the indexing operations aren't counted. After all, `a[i][j]` requires 2 additions: `*(*(a + i) + j)`.

Comment: Count would be equal to 2(m)+2(n)+1

Comment: `d` and `e` is the last value of `j` and `i` at which its coming out of the loop. for e.g if you are running loop `for(i=0; i<=3; i++)`, in this it will first increment value of `i` then check condition `i<=3`. At `i=4` condition will fail and it comes out of the loop. that is the last value of `d` and `e` in you code.

Comment: As for each value of `i`, `j` is running `n` time, So total count will be `2(m)+2(m*n)+1`

Comment: @JorenHeit Yeah you are right. He is only considering the right side.
Thanks for clearing that.

Comment: @Himanshu Okay now I do understand the reason of d and e. Thanks.
But why i < m; i++ is only being counted as one operation?